# Convert string OAuth token to ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin

I have my own custom `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` implementation. I am using token-based security to communicate with WebApi.

In the headers there is a `Authorization` header with the bearer token. This works perfectly with WebApi.

My app has a dependency on a 3rd party MVC component. I want to pass the bearer token as part of the query string and the convert it to a `ClaimsPrincipal` to retrieve the current user.

What can I call in C# to convert a bearer token as a string to a `ClaimsPrincipal` (or any object which will enable me to read the user id claim)?

Comment: If the 'bearer token' is a jwt, you can use: http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/5.0.0-rc1-211161024 then you have access to all the claims.

Comment: could you pease elaborate better on your needs? they're not completely clear to me. Any Controller in your app should receive a `this.User` already set by whichever authentication framework you're using. You can then set `var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity` and find all your claims from there. Maybe it's not that easy to get the token itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions (in my case named OAuthOptions )and then you access the token format and use the unprotect function.

```
ticket = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(token);
```

Once you have the token, you can easily get the claims.